# Communicating between Virtual Machines: creating a named pipe?

Tags: networking, named-pipes, identifier, vmware-workstation

Using the latest release of VMware:

Trying to create a connection between two virtual machines (one with Windows OS, the other with a Linux OS)

[image: vmware connection]

My question is simply: how do you create a reference to the other virtual machine? com_1 is the default pipe name, but will clearly not refer specifically to the Linux OS machine which I wish to connect to. Is there some terminal code that can be used in Linux which will identify it as the other end of the named pipe?

Comment: named pipes are a windows-specific mechanism. You can't use them to connect linux and windows.

Comment: @bmargulies : are you sure? This article: http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/vmdialup/lib/vmware-console/help-manual/devices_serial_connect2vms_gsx.htm seems to suggest you can

Comment: Well, that's new to me: they are connecting a Windows named pipe on one end to some sort of a socket on the other. Imagine that.

Answer (score 4):

If you selected Output to named pipe, configure the named pipe.

a) (Windows host) Use the default pipe name, or type another pipe name.
The pipe name must begin with `\\.\pipe\` and must be the same on both the server and the client.
For example: `\\.\pipe\namedpipe`

b) (Linux host) Type /tmp/socket or another UNIX socket name in the first text box.
The pipe name must be the same on both the server and the client.

c) To send debugging information to an application on the host system, select This end is the server from the first drop-down menu and select The other end is an application from the second drop-down menu.

d) To send debugging information to another virtual machine, select This end is the server from the first drop-down menu and The other end is a virtual machine from the second drop-down menu.

e) To connect the port to the virtual machine when the virtual machine powers on, select Connect at power on.

f) Click Finish to add the virtual serial port to the virtual machine.

g) (Optional) On the Hardware tab, select the new serial port, select Yield CPU on poll, and click OK.

This option is useful if you are using debugging tools that communicate over a serial connection. If the serial port in the guest operating system is being used in polled mode rather than interrupt mode, you might notice performance issues. This option forces the virtual machine to yield processor time if the only task it is trying to do is poll the virtual serial port.

What to do next

If you set up a connection between two virtual machines, the first virtual machine is set up as *The server*. Repeat this procedure for the second virtual machine, but set it up as the client by selecting *This end is the client* when you configure the named pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Look at http://communities.vmware.com/thread/214146

Probably you just need add something like:

```
serial0.present = "TRUE"
serial0.fileType = "pipe"
serial0.fileName = "/tmp/com_1"
```

to the Linux OS .vmx file.